# Drag and drop filtering philosophy

Tags: ios, uitableview, drag-and-drop, drag

I have some entries in `uitableview` which are droppable and some which are not.
The question is for consistent user experience should I disallow
dragging them altogether or should I just filter them out during the drop?

The issue is that `dropSessionDidUpdate` is invoked often
and I saw cases when I released the drop before green indicator has appeared
and drop did not happen. So it does not seem like I could iterate
over all the drop items in the array deciding if I should return drop proposal
operation `.forbidden` if ALL the items are unsuitable for droppage.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: allowing dragging invalid items would cause issues
dropping public.whatever content outside of your app.

But then how do I explain why users longpress on some tableview rows
and nothing happens?